# Javascript validation not working if i have more than one row

Tags: javascript, php, validation

The problem i'm facing here is javascript validation not working if there is more than one row. Why doesn't it validate the when there is more than one row?

**Javascript**

```
function mstatusvalidate()
{
    if(document.mstatus.mealstatus.value == "empty")
    {
        alert("Meal status field should not be empty.");
        document.mstatus.mealstatus.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**PHP** and **HTML**

```
if( mysql_result($m_result, $i, 'ActiveStatus') != 'empty' )
        {
            if( mysql_result($m_result, $i, 'ActiveStatus') == 'Y' )
            {
                echo "<td class=green >Active</td>";
            }
            else if( mysql_result($m_result, $i, 'ActiveStatus') == 'N' )
            {
                echo "<td class=red >Inactive</td>";
            }
        }
        else
            {
                echo "<td><form name=mstatus method=post onsubmit=return(mstatusvalidate()); action='voucherstatus_update.php?id_meal= " . mysql_result($m_result, $i, 'MealPlanID') . "'><select name=mealstatus><option value=empty></option><option value=active>Active</option><option value=inactive>Inactive</option></select><input type=submit class=update_status title=\"Update " . mysql_result($result, $i, 'GuestName') . " meals status\" value=Update></form></td>";
            }
```

Image of the html combobox form

[image: This is the image]

Comment: `not working` is not a very good problem description. What error do you get? What happens when you try the above code and how is that different from the expected result?

Comment: i didn't get alert message when i have more than one rows

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the FORM as seen from the browser for more than one row at a time so we know how to rewrite the JavaScript?

Comment: shouldn't it be document.forms["mstatus"] or give select name=mealstatus, a id and get document.getElementById('id').value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

**JavaScript**:

```
function mstatusvalidate(f)
{
    if(f.mealstatus.value == "empty")
    {
        alert("Meal status field should not be empty.");
        f.mealstatus.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**PHP**:

```
echo "<td><form method=post onsubmit=\"return mstatusvalidate(this)\"; action='voucherstatus_update.php?id_meal= " . mysql_result($m_result, $i, 'MealPlanID') . "'><select name=mealstatus><option value=empty></option><option value=active>Active</option><option value=inactive>Inactive</option></select><input type=submit class=update_status title=\"Update " . mysql_result($result, $i, 'GuestName') . " meals status\" value=Update></form></td>";
```

Comment: Thanks... its working. Now you removed the form name (name=mstatus) and you mentioned this inside the return function. Can you please explain me why its not working before & why its working now?

Comment: `document.mstatus` returns a reference to the <form> element as expected but only if one such element with that name exists. If more than one element with that name exists, then it returns a collection instead, which is indistinguishable from an array for most purposes, and you need to use `document.mstatus[0]` to refer to the first <form> element and `document.mstatus[1]` to refer to the second <form> element etc. In order to refer to the correct <form> element from the JavaScript callback, I am passing `this` to the callback which is a reference to the <form> being submit.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have several select with the same name. If you send the form via http this is a problem. If you collect the datas via javascript and then send them to the server via ajax this should work.

In the latter case you have to change the method to collect the select for test. The following code is a proof of concept, it works only with the latest browsers, but should be a good starting point for a solution.

```
function mstatusvalidate()
{
    var collection = document.querySelectorAll("select[name=mealstatus]");
    for(var i=0; i< collection.length; i++) {
        if (collection[i].value === "empty") {
            alert("Meal status field should not be empty.");
            collection[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Kind of overkill resorting to `document.querySelectorAll` when JavaScript had a way to handle this functionality since its beginning. Also the logic you're using here is flawed since there's multiple forms which have no relationship with one another. So requiring all forms to be valid when only one form can be sent anyways isn't the correct way to validate the data and will prevent the page from being used in the intended way.

Comment: Also the `focus()` would fail because `document.mstatus` returns a collection whenever two or more forms exist. I believe you meant `collection[i].focus();`

Comment: @Ultimater I've already stated that this is a proof of concept. Not meant to be used in production. The querySelectorAll was meant to stress the collection nature of the selection and the need to manipulate such a data structure. For the focus you were right.